# System.ServiceModel.Primitives is simply not being referenced at build time (though corresponding DLL seems to be properly installed)

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

In a .Net Standard 2.0 project, I am unable to load a reference to System.ServiceModel.Primitives... It says that Primitives doesn't exist on the System.ServiceModel namespace, even though I installed the System.ServiceModel.Http (v 4.10.3, which also depends on the System.ServiceModel.Primitives package) as well as the System.ServiceModel.Primitives (v 4.10.3) nuget packages, and in the properties for the dependencies, after being installed, it shows the correct path to the DLL files corresponding to the packages installed. I just don't get why/how it is not able to resolve the System.ServiceModel.Primitives dependency.

I've tried searching around online, on Stack Overflow, and trying various things to get past this dependency issue, but I'm really not sure how to proceed from here.

This dependency is used in some legacy WCF code in a larger legacy service that I've been upgrading in order to use newer (non-discontinued) SDKs.

Comment: Can you provide more details and error reports, please.

Comment: @QIYou thanks, but I actually reverted off from .NET Standard 2.0 for that particular project (so this stopped becoming a blocker for me). There wasn't really a need for it, other than better tooling. Looking forward to better tooling on new solutions though.

Answer (score 0):

**.NET Standard** is a formal specification of **.NET APIs** that are available on multiple .NET implementations.

**.NET Standard 2.0** supports **ASP.NET Framework 4.6.1-4.8.1** and **ASP.NET Core**.

Here is the documentation for [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-1-0)

So I think you probably created **Asp.Net Core project**. However **ASP.NET Core** project does not support **System.ServiceModel.Primitives**.

You can use **CoreWCF.Primitives**. Here is the relevant [documentation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CoreWCF.Primitives/).